# UIDatePicker not showing expected time

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I'm very new to Swift and XCode. When choosing the time in the UIDatePicker, the time always seems to be 17 hours off. I can't find anything in the Apple Documentation explaining why this would happen.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(timePicker.date)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the date picker show the date you are expecting and only the print statement is wrong? or does the picker also show an incorrect date? Also What time zone are you in? My hunch is the date picker is correct but the print statement is printing out the date/time in UTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @PJayRushton, you get a UTC date printed.

In order to get your local timezone, you can modify your printing code to something like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm" // or whatever other format you want
        print(dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker!.date))
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same issue when I tried the code in my playground.
However, I came up with a workaround and implemented it this way.

```
var timePicker = UIDatePicker()
var currentTime = timePicker.date
print(timePicker.date.description(with: .current))
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way but it got the job done at least.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the **UIDatePicker.Mode** property of date picker. Also, you can set the **dateFormat** property to get the date in desired format.

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.dateAndTime
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
let selDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
print(selDate)
```